# Query parameters in Durandal router

Tags: durandal

I have a route that has query parameters. When activating the view, the query parameters are gathered and passed to a server side request.  I don't know what the parameters are.  I simply pass them to the server for processing.

In my viewmodel activate method, the context parameter is an object that contains the query parameters, plus two extra items: routeInfo and router. Durandal adds these to the query parameters.  First, I don't want those passed on to the server side. Second, if my query parameters also contains those two names, then they get overwritten.

I've looked through the router code and find where they are added to my params (in dequeueRoute), but find no way to prevent the addition, nor a way to get just my query parameters without them.

Does anyone know how I can get the query parameters without the routeinfo and router?  And out of curiosity, why are they added in the first place instead of a separate argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your right. I went ahead and tested what your saying and it seems that all the querystring parameters are being written to the context parameter.

so if you have a route like this:

`http://www.somesite.com/#/services/?routeInfo=value1&router=value2&param1=value3`

inside your activate method:

```
define(function() {
   return {
     activate: function(context) {
        console.log(context);
     }
   };
});
```

Then the `context` will be a json object of:

```
{ 
   routeInfo: {...}, // info object of moduleId and such
   router: {...}, // reference to the router.js pluggin
   param1: 'value3',
   splat: ['?routeInfo=value1&router=value2&param1=value3']
}
```

So, the querystring parameters are being written to the `context` object but if your querystring parameters are of `routeInfo`, `router`, or `splat` then bad things will happen.  Especially if its `splat`!

So, I guess just dont use those parameters..

Also, as you can see your querystring parameters are passed to the splat object. You can easily parse the querystring by doing:

```
function parsePlease(queryString) {
   var obj = {};
   var splitV = queryString.split('&');
   for (var i = 0, max = splitV.length; i< max; i++) {
      obj[splitV[i].split('=')[0]] = splitV[i].split('=')[1];
   }
   return obj;
}
```

Something like that. You might want to improve on that.. i just whipped it up.

Also, you can also get your query string params from the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location) object.  From the `window.location.search` object it will contain everything after the `?` deliminator.

Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Unless I'm doing something else wrong, it appears I only get the splat property if I also use mapAuto. I guess I could use it, but not sure what else that will do to my routing. In any case, from my playing around further, it appears the best thing for me is to simply use window.location.search.  I really wish there was a way to do this without having to parse the string myself.

Comment: durandal is in its early stages and the router module is a pluggin.  Give it some time.. I bet it will be much better in the coming months.  The library is still being actively worked on.  It's good your using it now because as it grows you'll be that much more knowledgeable.